# Session ID is duplicated, swapping the user details

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, express, passport.js

I have built an e-commerce website using express.js. The authentication method used is passport.js. We store the cookie with all the information we need in redis.

Everything was fine until we started driving more traffic.

Now the problem

When user A comes to the site, logs in and makes a purchase, every day or two 2-3 customer details are wrong.

User A comes to the site and make a purchase. The email and address of the user A sometimes becomes the email and address of user B

We cannot easily replicate this as this happens only once in 50 purchases.or sometimes twice in 50 purchases.

So I had to call all my contacts and check what is the wrong thing we have done. And curiously one guy replied me that he also have the same issue. He is saying it the problem with passport.js, and he wrote custom authentication method to remove passport and till now he has not faced any issue. He also uses exactly my set up. NODE-EXPRESS-REDIS

I am quoting his words here

Whenever a user logs in from one computer, open the site in another computer then refresh the page, You can see the logged in details of the first user in second computer, and this issue is not frequent but it comes once in a while

Comment: You will have to post some code sooner or later..

Comment: This issue is caused by whatever is handling your session recognition. It sounds like you already know this. Unfortunately, even though Stack Overflow is full of experts who could solve this problem, Stack Overflow is not the place to request expert assistance with non-specific questions. SO is intended to be a repository of straightforward answers to straightforward questions, not open-ended requests for help. Without providing the source code that is causing the problem I do not think SO can be of help here.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the same session id for all users, which means if 2 people are using the site at the same time, they will share the same session and the data in it.  This is a really bad security floor for an e-commerce site